# Count zeroes amongst multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a pandas DataFrame which has 10 columns which contain either a 0, 1 or NaN. Here is an example dataframe that resembles what I have.

```
id     col_1 col_2 col_3
'jk3'  1     1     NaN
'kp2'  1     1     1
'po0'  0     1     0
'in6'  NaN   0     1
'ml5'  1     NaN   0
'lj3'  1     0     NaN
```

I want to add another column `df['correct']` that shows `False` if a `0` exists across the row, else shows `True`.

I attempted this by adding the series together:

```
df['correct'] = df[df.col_1 + df.col_2 + col_3]
```

but the `NaN` turned out to be a problem and showed `NaN` in rows that were supposed to be `True`

Is there any way I can implement it so that this is the output?

```
id     col_1 col_2 col_3 correct
'jk3'  1     1     NaN   True
'kp2'  1     1     1     True
'po0'  0     1     0     False
'in6'  NaN   0     1     False
'ml5'  1     NaN   0     False
'lj3'  1     0     NaN   False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use if `id` is column:

```
df['correct'] = df.iloc[:, 1:].ne(0).all(axis=1)
#alternative solution
#df['correct'] = ~df.iloc[:, 1:].eq(0).any(axis=1)
print (df)
      id  col_1  col_2  col_3  correct
0  'jk3'    1.0    1.0    NaN     True
1  'kp2'    1.0    1.0    1.0     True
2  'po0'    0.0    1.0    0.0    False
3  'in6'    NaN    0.0    1.0    False
4  'ml5'    1.0    NaN    0.0    False
5  'lj3'    1.0    0.0    NaN    False
```

**Details**:

First seelct all columns without first by [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
print (df.iloc[:, 1:])
   col_1  col_2  col_3
0    1.0    1.0    NaN
1    1.0    1.0    1.0
2    0.0    1.0    0.0
3    NaN    0.0    1.0
4    1.0    NaN    0.0
5    1.0    0.0    NaN
```

Compare by not equal by [`ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.ne.html):

```
print (df.iloc[:, 1:].ne(0))
   col_1  col_2  col_3
0   True   True   True
1   True   True   True
2  False   True  False
3   True  False   True
4   True   True  False
5   True  False   True
```

Last check [`all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) `True`s per rows:

```
print (df.iloc[:, 1:].ne(0).all(axis=1))
0     True
1     True
2    False
3    False
4    False
5    False
dtype: bool
```

And if `id` is index:

```
df['correct'] = df.ne(0).all(axis=1)
print (df)
       col_1  col_2  col_3  correct
id                                 
'jk3'    1.0    1.0    NaN     True
'kp2'    1.0    1.0    1.0     True
'po0'    0.0    1.0    0.0    False
'in6'    NaN    0.0    1.0    False
'ml5'    1.0    NaN    0.0    False
'lj3'    1.0    0.0    NaN    False
```

Answer (score 0):

Check df.count(), it gives non null count of dataframe, then you can assign it to true/false as you wish.